# Match a huge list of entries in a given text file

Tags: text, string-matching

I am trying to match a list of entries in a given text file. The list is quite huge. Its a list of organization names, where names can have more than one word. Each text file is a kind of usual write-up with several paragraphs, totaling to approximately 5000 words per txt. Its a plain text content, and there is no clear boundary by which I can locate organization names.

I am looking for a way by which all the entries from the list are searched in the text file and whichever gets matched are recognized and tagged.

Is there any tool or framework to do this?

I tried to go through all the text mining tools listed in Wikipedia, but none seems to match this need.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1:  Finite State Machine

You can combine your search terms into a finite state machine (FSM).  The resulting FSM can then scan a document for all the terms simultaneously in linear time.  Since the FSM can be reused on each document, the expense of creating it is amortized over all the text you have to search.

A good regular expression library will make an FSM under the covers.  Writing code to build your own is probably beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

The basic idea is to start with a regular expression that is an alternation of all your search terms.  Suppose your organization list consists of "cat" and "dog".  You'd combine those as `cat|dog`.  If you also had to search for "pink pigs", your regular expression would be `cat|dog|pink pigs`.

From the regular expression, you can build a graph.  The nodes of the graph are states, which keep track of what text you've just seen.  The edges of the graph are transitions that tell the state machine which state to go to given the current state and the next character in the input.  Some states are marked as "final" states, and if you ever get to one of those, you've just found an instance of one of your organizations.

Building the graph from all but the most trivial regular expressions is tedious and can be computationally expensive, so you probably want to find a well-tested regular expression library that already does this work.

## Approach 2:  Search for One Term at a Time

Depending on how many search terms you have, how many documents you have, and how fast your simple text searching tool is (possibly sub-linear), it may be best to just loop through the terms and search each document for each term as a separate command.  This is certainly the simplest approach.

```
for doc in documents:
   for term in search_terms:
       search(term, doc)
```

Note that nesting the loops this way is probably most friendly to the disk cache.

This is the approach I would take if this were a one-time task.  If you have to keep searching new documents (or with different lists of search terms), this might be too expensive.

## Approach 3:  Suffix Tree

Concatenate all the documents into one giant document, build a suffix tree, sort your search terms, and walk through the suffix tree looking for matches.  Most of the details for building and using a suffix array are in this [Jon Bentley article from Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/algorithm-alley/184404588), but you can find many other resources for them as well.

This approach is memory intensive, mostly cache-friendly, and thus very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **prefix tree** aka Trie.

Load all your candidate names into the prefix tree.
For your documents, match them against the tree.

A prefix tree looks roughly like this:

```
{}
+-> a
|   +-> ap
|   |   +-> ... apple
|   +-> az
|       +-> ... azure
+-> b
    +-> ba
        +-> ... banana republic
```

Comment: This is very similar to the finite-state machine approach.  The main difference is that the FSM has extra transitions to avoid backtracking.